# c# extract base class properties only based on derived class and return new base class object

Tags: c#

I have 2 classes `StaggingAttorney` and `Attorney`. I will use the `StaggingAttorney` to collect information about an attorney and once I have all the information I will use it to create an `Attorney` profile using the best results. The 2 classes look like this;

```
private class StaggingAttorney : CourtCase.Attorney
{
    public bool scraping = false;

    public bool scraped = false;

    public string caseNumber;

    public CourtCase.Attorney toAttorney()
    {
        CourtCase.Attorney attorney = new CourtCase.Attorney();
        return attorney;
    }

}
```

...and...

```
public class Attorney
{
    public string names;
    public string matchString;
    ...    
    public List<Identity> IdentityMatches = new List<Identity>();

    public List<Identity> getIdentityMatches()
    {
        return IdentityMatches;
    }
    public class Identity
    {
        public string names;
        public string barNumber;
        public string email;

        public string phoneNumber { get; internal set; }
        public object faxNumber { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

I have created a method called `CourtCase.Attorney toAttorney()` which you can see above. In this method I want to return a new `CourtCase.Attorney` with all `CourtCase.Attorney` inherited properties in the the `StaggingAttorney`

Comment: To be sure that you made your point clear, when "toAttorney()" on an StaggingAttorney is called, you would like to return a new "Attorney" object who has the same property values than the parent class of your StaggingAttorney?

Comment: You're already inheriting from that class. Why not doing a simple casting?

Comment: See this discussion for some ideas: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a096e04-a422-4c71-b628-2ccdfc54518d/casting-to-base-class?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 0):

As @derloopkat suggested, you can simply cast your ***"StaggingAttorney"*** instance to his parent class. (***"Attorney"*** in this case)

But if you really need a new instance of an ***"Attorney"*** with the same values than the parent ***"StaggingAttorney"*** just access to the parent fields of your ***"StaggingAttorney"*** object.

```
private class StaggingAttorney : CourtCase.Attorney
{
    public bool scraping = false;

    public bool scraped = false;

    public string caseNumber;

    public CourtCase.Attorney toAttorney()
    {
        CourtCase.Attorney attorney = new CourtCase.Attorney()
        {
            names = this.names,
            matchString = this.matchString,
            [... Initialize the other properties ...]
        };
        return attorney;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of a child class you are also creating the parent. So there are no many scenarios where you need to make another new instance from a `child.ToParent()` method. Having a conversion method like this makes more sense when one class is not inheriting from the other.

```
var attorney = new StaggingAttorney() { scraped = false };
attorney.names = "John"; //During the scraping process
attorney.scraped = true;
CourtCase.Attorney court = (CourtCase.Attorney)attorney; //casting
Console.WriteLine(court.names); //returns "John"
```

No need to copy data, because the child inherited `names` from its parent.